# Taking count in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

How to take a row count of a list which is in word document?? If the same list is in excel I am able to take the count using aggregate operator but in word document it is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the answer from @awchisholm as it's the easiest solution.  However, if you have several word documents this might become impractical. 
In this case you can use the operator Loop Zip files to unzip the word document and look inside the for the file /word/document.xml and using RapidMiner's text functions (or Read XML) look for each instance of `<w:p ...>...</w:p>`, this represents a new line so you can count them from there.

There is also an xml doc in the unzipped directory called /docProps/app.xml you can read this in to find some meta information about the document such as number of words, characters & pages. Unfortunately I've found that unreliable for number of lines which is why I recommend using the `<w:p>` tag to search.

Answer (score 0):

RapidMiner cannot easily read Word documents. You have to save the document as a text file and use the Read CSV operator to read the file.